# How do I extract the values of the innermost dictionary of a 3-level dictionary and save those values in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I have a 3-level nested dictionary whose structure is as follows:

Dictionary 1:
Keys: 1, 2, 3, 4. 1 stands for winter, 2 for spring, 3 for summer and 4 for autumn season.

Dictionary 2.
Keys: Years from 2005 to 2018.

Dictionary 3.
Keys:0 to 24. 0 to 24 for hourly average. Every key has values pertaining to the hourly average for that year of that season.

I am posting pictures of the 3 dictionaries as well.

I am a beginner in Python and so far I have tried the code below, but it is not giving me the desired ouput.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i, j, k): pm_10_abs_season[i][j][k] for i in pm_10_abs_season.keys() for j in pm_10_abs_season[i].keys() for k in pm_10_abs_season[i][j]}, orient = 'index')
```

[image]

The output I am getting looks like this:

[image]

I want to save the data in four Pandas DataFrames. One for each season. Then, I want to save the data in the following format:

Columns: Hour 0, Hour 1, Hour 3, ..., Hour 23

Rows: 2005, 2006, 2007, ..., 2018

So, the structure of the Pandas DataFrame would something like the following:

```
Year|Hour 0|Hour 1|Hour 2|...|Hour 23
-------------------------------------
2005|
2005|
2005|
... |
2018|
```

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible inputs, not images and only a reasonable number of rows. Also provide the matching expected output

Answer (score 0):

> I want to save the data in four Pandas DataFrames

I'll assume you're okay with nested DataFrames, since you haven't specified otherwise, and your desired output structure indicates nothing against it. If you want to flatten it, then I'd need more details about the output structure and preferably some sample of the output as well.

---

You could use something like

```py
def dict2df(seasonDict:dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame(seasonDict).T.rename_axis('Year', axis='rows')
    return df.rename(lambda n: f'Hour {n}', axis='columns')
```

or

```py
def dict2df(seasonDict:dict):
    return pd.DataFrame([{'Year': yk, **{
        f'Hour {hk}': hdf for hk, hdf in yd.items()
    }} for yk, yd in seasonDict.items()]).set_index('Year')
```

[ I wrote the second one before I realized/discovered that *<kbd>{column->{index->value}}</kbd>* is a valid input structure for `pd.DataFrame` and that the 4 dictionaries in `pm_10_abs_season` have an *<kbd>{index->{column->value}}</kbd>* structure, which just needs to be [transposed](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) (`.T`) to get quite close to your desired output structure. The second version does appear to be a tiny bit faster (about 10%) but I'm not sure if you'd consider that significant enough to matter.]

---

Anyway, I generated a **test input** ([<kbd>`seasons_dfs`</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBVce.png)) to mimic your `pm_10_abs_season` (but the DataFrames inside just have one cell containing the string `'<DataFrame>'`)

```py
seasonRef = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(['winter','spring','summer','autumn'],1)}
# seasonRef = {1: 'winter', 2: 'spring', 3: 'summer', 4: 'autumn'}

seasons_dfs = {sk: {yk: {
    hk: pd.DataFrame(
        {f'{sn[0]}_{str(yk)[-2:]}':{f'hour{hk:0>2}':f'<DataFrame>'}}
    ) for hk in range(24)
} for yk in range(2005,2019)} for sk,sn in seasonRef.items()}
```

and then used the function <sup>(*`dict2df(sd)`*)</sup> to convert it to a dictionary of DataFrames ([<kbd>`nestedDfs`</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuH1l.png)).

```py
nestedDfs = {
    seasonRef.get(s, f'[season {s}]'): dict2df(sd) 
    for s, sd in seasons_dfs.items()
}
```

The 4 DataFrames inside `nestedDfs` should have your desired output structure:
[image: winter]
[image: spring]
[image: summer]
[image: autumn]